# Show that a fraction in it's lowest terms has a terminating decimal expansion iff b is not divisible by primes other than 2 and 5.

Tags: number-theory

I have just started working through the book "Discrete Mathematics for Computer Scientists" by John Truss and unfortunately have fallen at the first hurdle.

Given the question in the title, the model answer is as follows:-

1) $\frac{a}{b}$ is an integer for some $n$ when multiplied by $10^{n}$

2) Given (1), $b$ divides $a \times 10^{n}$ as there are no common factors.

3) $b$ divides $10^{n}$ so cannot be divisible by primes other than 2 and 5.

I am unclear on how the author asserts statement 3.

Comment: If $b$ were divisible by a prime $p\neq 2,5$ then $p$ would divide $10^n=2^n5^n$, in contradiction of unique factorization.

Comment: Stepping from 2) to 3) uses  *Gauß's lemma* : since $b\mid a\times 10^n$ and is coprime to $a$, it must divide $10^n$.